# Problem In Create PROCEDURE IN Mariadb/MySQL on phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

My Problem it is in Create the Procedure in Mariadb/MySQl on phpMyAdmin.
When i wirte the code of create of Procedure. there are not any problem here.
the problem begin When i try to excute the code.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE pro_Insert_tblperson(IN FirstName varchar(50), IN MiddeName varchar(50), IN LastName varchar(50), IN Pass varchar(50), IN PerGender INT, OUT PersonID INT )
BEGIN
    DECLARE pvrPersonID INT;
    SELECT MAX(Id) INTO pvrPersonID FROM tblperson;
    
    INSERT INTO tblperson( First_Name, Midde_Name, Last_Name, Password, Gender) VALUES (FirstName,MiddeName,LastName,Pass,PerGender);
    
    DECLARE NewPersonID INT;
    SELECT MAX(Id) INTO NewPersonID FROM tblperson;
    
    IF NewPersonID > pvrPersonID THEN
        SET PersonID = NewPersonID;
    ELSE
        SET PersonID = 0;
    END IF;
END 
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The compiler returns to me, This Error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE NewPersonID INT;
    SELECT MAX(Id) INTO NewPersonID FROM tblperson;...' at line 8
```

I don't know what I do it???

Comment: Did you note the error is on the **second** DECLARE statement?  Please put them at the start of your PROCEDURE, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/bDwVoMC1

Comment: Read about `LAST_INSERT_ID()` -- Then simplify the query and/or avoid an error with `MAX` if two connections are performing the same procedure at the same time.